# Condition on dictionary

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using NEO4j 3.0 and as attribute I had a dictionnary. Here is an example for an property of a relationship:

```
R1 :2016-09:{'x': 296, 'y': 8} 
R2 : 2016-08:{'x': 481, 'y': 13}
R3 : 2016-08:{'x': 300, 'y': 13}
```

I'm looking to retrieve paths that the key 'x' satisfied certain conditions for a certain date. So, I tried this as suggested in old post :

```
MATCH (A:Airport {code:'AAA'}),
      (B:Airport {code:'BBB'}),
      (A)-[r:`2016-08`]-(B)
WHERE r.x>'300'
RETURN r
```

It sould give me only R2 but I get nothing.

So, I'm looking for the syntaxe to retrieve the value of key when the property key is a dictionary.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a "dictionary"? The property has a name (key if you will) and a value. Are you sure your problem is not the comparison of a numeric value with a string (`r.x > '300'` instead of `r.x > 300`)?

Comment: The property value is a set of many keys/values : {'x': 296, 'y': 8}  and I want to retrieve relations that has an x greather than 300

Comment: That's 2 properties, unless the property is actually set with `{'prop': '{"x": 296, "y": 8}'}`, i.e. JSON as a string, in which case you can't query something inside.

Comment: So, I have to represent like that :
{'prop':'x':296} and {'prop':'y':8}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your relationship is created like

```
MATCH (a:Airport {code: "AAA"}), (b:Airport {code: "BBB"})
CREATE (a)-[:`2016-08` {x: 296, y: 8}]->(b)
```

it has 2 properties (`x` and `y`) which you can query and use in `WHERE` clauses, return, whatever.

If, however, you create a single property with a complex JSON-like structure inside as a string like this

```
MATCH (a:Airport {code: "AAA"}), (b:Airport {code: "BBB"})
CREATE (a)-[:`2016-08` {prop: "{x: 296, y: 8}"}]->(b)
```

you can't query the content of the `prop` property: it's a string and opaque to the Cypher engine. You only get string operations, like `STARTS WITH`, `ENDS WITH`, `CONTAINS`, etc.

**TL;DR** if you need to query something, it needs to be a property by itself.

Comment: My relationship is created like this (using py2neo library) : 
`                  node_properties = {field:row[field]}
                  r = Relationship(source_airport_node,field ,destination_airport_node, **node_properties)
                   graph.create(r)``

Comment: Yes, so it depends on what the value of `row[field]` is (ultimately, what's in your CSV): either it's a simple numeric or string value, or it's a JSON-like structure. Have you looked at your relationships in the Neo4j browser to better understand how it's actually set? Just run `MATCH (a:Airport {code: "AAA"}), (b:Airport {code: "BBB"}) RETURN a, b`, it will display the 2 nodes and a number of their relationships, and you'll be able to see the properties for each of them.

Comment: it displays only the 2 nodes with their properties and not their relationships

Comment: So, unless you have turned the auto-completion off (bottom right of the result frame), you don't have relationships between your nodes and your query won't return anything.

Comment: When I click on my relationship, I got this:
<id>:230941 2015-11:{'x': 29654, 'y': 36367}2016-01:{'x': 35581, 'y': 224}.
So, I don't have any idea how it's actually set in Neo4j.

Comment: If that's really one relationship, it seems to differ from what you wanted to create. It looks like you have 2 properties, called `2015-11` and `2016-01`, with values that look like JSON (so you can't query "sub-properties").

Comment: I tried to recreate my relationships using this :
MATCH (a:Airport {code: "AAA"}), (b:Airport {code: "BBB"})
CREATE (a)-[:`2016-08` {x: 296, y: 8}]->(b)

Now, I'm using this query to get all relationships that match certain condition on x :

MATCH (a:Airport {code:'AAA'}),
      (a)-[*]-(b)
WHERE r.x>'4'
RETURN a,b

I got error. Can you please coorect me the query

Comment: There's no `r` declared in your query, and you're also comparing a numeric value (`x`) with a string (`'4'`). Try `MATCH (a:Airport {code:'AAA'})-[r]-(b) WHERE r.x > 4 RETURN a, b` instead.

Comment: I used your suggestion to recreate my graph using this:
`MATCH (a:Airport {code: "AAA"}), (b:Airport {code: "BBB"})
CREATE (a)-[:`2016-08` {x: 296, y: 8}]->(b)` but I got a problem when I want to get all x for a period greater than `2016-08`

Comment: We're pretty far from the original question, SO isn't really a discussion forum. If you need to find relationships across a more versatile period than a single month, maybe it shouldn't be encoded into the name of the relationship. Well, you can still match on multiple relationship types using `[:A|B]`, but it means generating even more different queries, which need to be parsed by the Cypher engine, etc.